# How can I push the codebase to bitbucket using Bash on Azure Devop ubuntu agent?

Tags: azure-devops

Here is what I am trying to do:

- I have a pipeline which runs on ubuntu image.
- As a part of pipeline, I want to push commits to the bitbucket cloud.
- I have written a simple bash script to do this but it seems like

Azure DevOps pipeline task

```yaml
- job: Git_Merge
  steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        filePath: merge.sh
      env:
        SOURCE_BRANCH: ${{ parameters.source_branch }}
        TARGET_BRANCH: ${{ parameters.target_branch }}
```

merge.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "SOURCE BRANCH IS $SOURCE_BRANCH"
echo "TARGET BRANCH IS $TARGET_BRANCH"

if [[ "$SOURCE_BRANCH" == "$TARGET_BRANCH" ]]; then
   echo "Source and Target branch names are the same so no merge is needed."
   exit
fi

echo "GIT CHECKOUT $TARGET_BRANCH"
git checkout "$TARGET_BRANCH"

echo "GIT STATUS"
git status

echo "GIT MERGE"
git merge "origin/$SOURCE_BRANCH" -m "Merge $SOURCE_BRANCH to $TARGET_BRANCH [skip ci]"

echo "GIT STATUS"
git status

echo "GIT PUSH"
git push origin

echo "GIT STATUS"
git status
```

Error

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': terminal prompts disabled
```

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paxPQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when DevOps agent checks out your code, it doesn't store the credentials. That's why, when you do `git push`, git tries to ask you for username and password, but there's no interactive terminal to read it from.

To store the credentials, use `checkout` task explicitly, as the first step:

```yaml
steps:
  - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: true
```

You might also need to configure `user.email` and `user.name` to be able to commit:

```yaml
  - pwsh: |
      git config user.email ${{variables['user.email']}}
      git config user.name ${{variables['user.name']}}
    displayName: configure git credentials
```

After that, git commands should work as expected.

Comment: This worked and really appreciate your help.